# Alternative to Crocodile Clips

Tags: open-source, simulation

I want an alternative to Crocodile Clips 3.5, the educational electric simulator. I already know [Yenka](http://www.yenka.com/en/Yenka_Technology/) but I'm looking for something different. It would be better if the program is open source and runs on Ubuntu.

Requirements:

- Do basic electric and electronic simulation
- Free for personal use
- Run on Ubuntu

Optional:

- Open source
- Posibility to add more components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/home/). Fritzing is open source, free software available for Windows, Mac and Linux.

> Fritzing is an open-source hardware initiative that makes electronics accessible as a creative material for anyone.

Fritzing has pretty good community, you can find many tutorials describing most of the features. Their web page contains examples project but there is much more examples in the application which are great. It has great support for Arduino (one of the best).
Here is a [video describing simulation with arduino board](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7kuLn-KHBY).